# screencast of app is blinking with Crosswalk enabled for android, cordova

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, crosswalk, screencast

I switched from GapDebug to Crosswalk remote debugging. Everything is fine with exception of 'screencast' in Developer Tools, which is blinking with 5 fps (when I use Crosswalk).

If I switch to 'Elements' tab and move mouse over any DOM element (make it active), the blinking stops. With GapDebug I had no issue. It was nice to ignore physical device and debug app on a computer screen.

May be someone faced similar issue before, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find proper solution but blinking is cased by automatic animation (transition) of selector on a page. To fix problem I simply removed automatic animation during production and will enable them back when I release app. If anyone can find other solution, please update.